# what Camera save() and restore() method really do?

Tags: android

what the `save()` and `restore()` methods in the [Camera](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Camera.html) 
 class do ? can any one explain ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Camera class that you linked to, android.hardware.Camera does not have a save() or restore() method.

Why do you think it does?  Where are you seeing it?

Peter

Comment: He refers to [android.graphics.Camera](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Camera.html).

Answer (score 1):

android.graphics.Canvas and android.graphics.Camera classes help you to manipulate transformation matrix (3D transformations especially for android.graphics.Camera).

The top of matrix stack is applied for transformation, so if you want to manipulate new transformation matrix,

1. you should push the current matrix into the stack by calling Camera.save() or Canvas.save() in order to remember it and
2. transform the new matrix, draw something and the like,
3. after finishing it, you should pop the previous matrix out from the stack by calling Camera.restore() or Canvas.restore() in order to remove the current transformation and come back to the recently saved one and continue on it.

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

I looked up the source to android.graphics.Camera. Those two methods are native methods. You might find these links to Android XRef useful (since I only know java, not C). [android.graphics.Camera native source](http://androidxref.com/source/xref/frameworks/base/core/jni/android/graphics/Camera.cpp), and [SkCamera](http://androidxref.com/source/xref/external/skia/src/utils/SkCamera.cpp), an included file which save and restore use.